# Is there any built-in way in Yii framework that enables AJAX form submission?

Tags: ajax, forms, yii

In the `CustomerController`, I have the `create` action:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Customer;

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model, 'customer-form');

    //only support ajax saving
    if (isset($_POST['Customer']) && Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
              $model->setAttributes($_POST['Customer']);
              $saveSuccess = $model->save();
              if ($saveSuccess) {
                        //should echo a success message                                                     
              }
              else {                            
                        //should echo error messages
              }

              Yii::app()->end();
    }


    $this->render('create', array('customer' => $model));
}
```

In the view, I am using the CActiveform:

```
  $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id' => 'customer-form',
      'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
       'clientOptions'=>array(
          'validateOnSubmit'=>false          
               )
          )
  );
```

As you can see, I set `enableAjaxValidation` to true, but I set the client options `validateOnSubmit` to false.

If I set it to true, when the form submits, it will **first** send an AJAX POST request to the server and then the server will return error messages (if any) in JSON format, CActiveForm will display the error summary automatically in the view and blocks the form submission.

If no error is found, the form will then do a **second** POST request (which is non-AJAX) and actually submit the form.

But this is not the behavior I am after.

Ideally, I would like to have a **single** AJAX POST request such that when the form submits, the server will return success or error message and CActiveForm will display them automatically.

Is this something built-in in Yii or I have to write my own codes doing this?

Comment: Be sure to use "Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest" to check if the request is an Ajax one.

Answer (score 4):

To perform ajax submission you need to replace the usual `CHtml::submitButton()` with `ajaxSubmitButton()`. Check it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However, I want the validation and form submission to be in a single AJAX POST request.

Comment: Of course! I'm sorry, I hadn't read the question with much attention... now I see... and actually the solutions is even simpler, but let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Using `ajaxSubmitButton()`, the form of course, will send an AJAX (instead of a non-AJAX) POST request to the server. But since this POST request is not initiated by the CActiveForm, CActiveForm will not catch its response in the client side, so no error or success message will be automatically displayed.

Comment: +1 simple solution, @bobo you'll have to write up your own code, to catch the response. lemme know if you need help with that.